# Loss of precision at run time when linking against specific libraries in C

Tags: c, precision

I have a somewhat odd problem that I have no real idea how to tackle.

I have a program that uses long doubles to do most of the math present, up until now that has worked fine.  Recently I wanted to use MLAPACK, which is a high precision version of lapack that uses double double and quad double types in order to do matrix solves.  Unfortunately when i link against the libraries for MLAPACK, i lose precision in the original program.

Ie.  If i just do a simple sum of 2 numbers:

```
long double a =  50000.55964442486829568679 
long double b =  0.006514624142341807720713032
```

when i *dont* link against MLAPACK i get (correctly for long double)

```
long double a + b = 50000.5661590490106374945
```

when i do link against this library i get:

```
long double a + b = 50000.56615904901264002547
```

ie, they differ at the level of double precision rather than long double.

The thing is, i have no idea how to go about trying to work out what is causing this change.  I assume there must be a function in MLAPACK that is also defined in the original program, and that it is calling the wrong one, but that original program is large (and not written by me).

The code is compiled on a linux system, with the MLAPACK libraries being linked against being .so files, everything is being compiled with the same version of gcc/gfortran etc.

I'm sure this is not the most well posed of questions, but i dont really understand why this would happen.. any ideas where to even begin looking for a solution?

Cheers

Comment: You said that "lapack that uses double double and quad double types". Why did you use 'long double' instead of 'double double' or 'quad double'?  How is 'long double' treated in MLAPACK?

Comment: your literals are of type `double`. Use the `L` suffix to make them `long double` - eg. `0.006514624142341807720713032L`

Comment: Oh, so that was just an example, the actual thing is:

    long double batCheck = psr[p].obsn[i].sat;
    long double corrCheck = getCorrectionTT(psr[p].obsn+i))/SECDAY
                + (psr[p].obsn[i].correctionTT_TB
                   -psr[p].obsn[i].troposphericDelay
                   +psr[p].obsn[i].roemer -
                   shapiroDelay - psr[p].obsn[i].tdis1 - psr[p].obsn[i].tdis2)/SECDAY;

    longdouble AddCorr = batCheck + corrCheck;

those are just the numbers that correspond to these 3 terms.

Comment: what is `LDBL_DIG` (in `<float.h>`) set to for both cases (just print it to stdout) ? Is it the same ?

Comment: In both cases LDBL_DIG is 18, which sounds right?

Comment: 18 looks like it is indeed the precision you're getting in both cases (they're both inaccurate after about 18 digits when compared to the real sum of a and b), so the difference between the two values is not caused by a difference in precision, but more likely by a difference in computation (order eg.).

Comment: or in other words : I don't see anything wrong - this is what you can expect from floating point types. Maybe you were expecting a better precision than 18 digits from a `long double` ?

Comment: Hmm, but there must be some loss in precision, as it gives me demonstrably the correct answer across multiple datasets without linking the library, and demonstrably the wrong answer for those same datasets with the library.. it seems like its changing 1 or 2 places too soon?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're compiling your program for Windows, as "32 bit", not "64 bit".  If you're using Microsoft Visual C, add this line before you start doing math:

```
_control87( _PC_64, _MCW_PC );    /* requires: #include <float.h> */
```

If you're using a different compiler then you may need to use a different function.

(I kind of doubt you're using MSVC, because it doesn't have "long double" as a distinct floating-point type.  What are you using, anyway?)

FULL EXPLANATION:

What's happening is that the floating-point unit inside your CPU is having its precision level changed by the startup code in the MLAPACK library.

The x87 FPU can run in any of three modes: single-precision (24 bits of precision), double-precision (53 bits of precision), and extended-precision (64 bits of precision, a/k/a long double).  In Microsoft Visual C, the precision mode is set by the `_control_87` built-in function; it might be different in your compiler.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx

Typically, the precision mode is set in the "startup code" for the C run-time library, which is included whenever you build a C program.  Your program doesn't *really* start with `main()`, but with some other "entry point" inside the C run-time library. The code at that entry point sets everything up so a C program can run, then calls your `main` function.  And if your program has long-double precision normally, that means that the entry point function must have called `_control87(_PC_64, _MCW_PC)` to set 64 bit long-double precision control.

So why is it changing when you link to MLAPACK?  I would guess that MLAPACK is a DLL (dynamically-linked library), or at some point it happens to load a DLL.  DLLs also have their own C run-time libraries (they're much more like separate executables than ordinary static libraries are) -- and especially if MLAPACK was built with a different compiler, it would have a different C run-time library with its own startup code.  *And that startup code sets the x87 FPU to 53-bit (double) precision!*

So the answer is: you need to make sure you call `_control87(_PC_64, _MCW_PC)`, or whatever the equivalent is on your compiler, to set to "long double" precision in your program before you start doing math.  It might be OK just to do it in `main`, as one of the first things you do.  Or maybe it is necessary to do *something* involving MLAPACK first, just to make sure MLAPACK is completely started up.  Like you might invert a 1x1 matrix, kind of a dumb thing, and then set to 64-bit precision -- basically you're undoing the damage done by MLAPACK's C run-time library startup.

Note: on Windows, 64-bit programs don't use the x87 floating-point unit at all, and so they never have "long double" precision.  That's why I assume you're building a 32 bit program.  And if this is Linux or Mac, I don't know what's going on!

Comment: I believe 64-bit programs compiled with MinGW-w64 GCC do have extended precision for `long double` calculations, as well as (independently) the option to use fp87 math through [`-mfpmath=387`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options). I believe your "Note" only applies to the MSVC compiler, and I'd guess the Intel compiler has options to extend the fp calculation's precision as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this is on a linux system (sorry should have said).

Everything is compiled with gcc/g++/gfortran, but it is linking against .so files

Comment: OK, you're using GCC on Linux.  Let's assume the same thing is happening as I discussed -- you'll just need to use different functions.  It's a bit harder to read and write the precision control on Linux, because there are no nice macros for accessing fields of the x87 control word, but it can be done.  Read: http://christian-seiler.de/projekte/fpmath/

Comment: First off, you're going to want to write code that reads the precision control and displays it (using `_FPU_GETCW`).  Then put that code into a normal program (not linked with MLAPACK), and into an MLAPACK-linked program.  If my theory is right, you will see extended-precision in the first, and double-precision in the second.

Comment: If the problem is a change in precision control, the fix is to use `_FPU_SETCW` to explicitly set the precision control to extended precision.  That is the same thing I describe in my comment, only I use `_control87` instead.